# How can I do a self-join in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, self-join

Here is my code:

```
$role_id = Auth::user()->role_id;

$related = Page::where('path', $request->path())->where('method', $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"])->first()->related;
$pages   = Page::where('related', $related)->get();

foreach ($pages as $page){
    $accessGiven = page_role::where('role_id', $role_id)->where('page_id', $page->id)->first();
    if ( sizeof($accessGiven) > 0 ) {
        return $next($request);
    }
}

return redirect('/');
```

It works well logically, but it is a little slow for huge dataset. You know, it's actually a middleware and will be executed before most of requests.

Anyway, I guess I can combine line 2 and line 3 and make one query of them. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: You mean you want to join `$related` and `$pages` in one query?

Comment: @HirenGohel In my project, some pages are related to each other. Now I want to get all related pages by having the identifire of one page. The `related` column specifies related pages *(all related pages have identical number)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

In your Page model:

```
public function relatedPages(){
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'related', 'related');
}
```

then

```
$pages = Page::where('path', $request->path())->where('method', $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"])->first()->relatedPages
```

Comment: Also just for my information, do you know how can I fix the error of [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ba92a86799f3f85233d564cd70cb2046)? It throws `Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Middleware....`

Comment: @stack Try: `$pages = Page::where('related', function($query, $request) use($request) {
  $query->where('path', $request->path())->where('method', $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"])->first()->related;
})->get();`

Comment: Now error changed: `Cannot use lexical variable $request as a parameter name`

Comment: You need to pass any other data in `use()` statement except to `$request`!

Comment: You can't launch the request in the query closure,

Answer (score -1):

Look in this example (I didn't test it):

```
$requestPath = $request->path();
$serverMethod = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
$pages = Page::where('related', function($query) use($requestPath,$serverMethod) { 
    $query->where('path', $requestPath )->where('method', 
    $serverMethod)->first()->related; }
)->get()
```

Comment: First of all, you should pass `$request` to the function *(in addition to the `$query`)*. Also your code throws `Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Middleware....` error.